# Equality check for double type gives strange results in C++

Tags: c++, double, equality

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    size_t N = 20;
    double from = 0.0;
    double to = 1.0;

    std::vector<double> xVec{};

    double h = (to - from) / double(N);
    for (double x = from; x <= to; x += h) { // not entering x == 1.0
        xVec.push_back(x);
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    double x = 0.9;
    const std::vector<double>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(xVec.begin(), xVec.end(), x);
    std::cout << x << " " << *it << " " << (x == *it) << "\n"; // states that 0.9 != 0.9
}
```

Which gives this really strange output:

```
0
0.05
0.1
0.15
0.2
0.25
0.3
0.35
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
0.6
0.65
0.7
0.75
0.8
0.85
0.9
0.95

0.9 0.9 0
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Why is my loop not entering `x == 1.0`, when I am using `<=` in the loop criterion?
2. How is it possible that a double given by `std::lower_bound` is not equal to another double with the same value?

Comment: Also see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision Default precision is 6. You don't see what's beyond that.

Comment: Demo of above comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xvrE1cb4e

Comment: `for (double x = from; x <= to; x += h)` -- In addition to what has been stated, floating point `for` loop variables and increment values does *not* guarantee that the loop will be executed the number of times you expect, all due to floating point and all the issues it brings with it.  Instead, if you know that you are to loop `n` times, then the `for` loop should use *integers* as the loop constraints, and inside the loop, you divide by the requisite amount for your calculations, i.e `for (int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) { double x = n / 10000.0; ... }` and then use `x` for further calculations.